# Lifted Diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Suppose to have a diffeomorphism $\phi$ of the d-dimensional torus to itself, and suppose to lift it to a morphism of $\mathbb{R}^d$ to itself. I have proved that is still invertible. How i proof that  it's  still differetiable. How the Jacobian of two diffeomorphsim are related?

Comment: I suppose by lifting to $\mathbb{R}^d$ you mean you got a $\Phi \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\pi \circ \Phi = \phi \circ \pi$ where $\pi \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{T}^d$ is the universal covering? $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: yes. Instead you mean "yes" because $π$  is a local diffeomorphism?

Comment: Yes, you can locally write $\Phi\lvert_V = (\pi\lvert_U)^{-1} \circ \phi \circ \pi\lvert_V$, which, as a composition of diffeomorphisms is a diffeomorphism ($U,\, V$ suitably chosen).